# How can I remove header and footer of web browser on printing document?

Tags: asp.net, html, css, printing

I am trying to `print some Cards` using `web browser`, the unfortunate part is that the browser writes a `header and footer` on my card and gets some space on my card which causes the card to be printed on two pages instead of one page.
How can I remove header and footer on the printing document ?

Thanks in advance .

Comment: You can't hide :). It's a browser setting. It can be changed at the client end obly.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an alternate stylesheet for printing, and then you define distinct rules for that format:

```
.my-header { display: none; }
.my-footer { display: none; }
```

And include the stylesheet with the proper media type, `print`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@media print 
{
    .noPrint 
    {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

save it in your stylesheet and add this class to elements which you don't want to print.

Answer (score 1):

The browser automaticaly adds a header and footer (with the url and such), you can not switch those off (unfortunately).

Answer (score 1):

The Headers and Footers added by the browser at printing can only be turned off locally by the end user. In IE for instance go to Print > Page Setup and edit the settings under Headers and Footers.

An alternative might be to create a PDF on the fly using something like http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/
This would allow you to set the page size, insert images, etc. dynamically which might meet your needs.